# How to export MYSQLdb table to CSV on Debian?

Tags: python, debian, export-to-csv, mysql-python

I want to export MYSQLdb tables into .csv format.

I tried this:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='***',
    passwd='***',
    db='database1',
    use_unicode=True,
    charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select * 
from example_table1
into outfile 'MYFOLDER'
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '';
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql_export_to_csv.py", line 46, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (1, 'Can\'t create/write to file \'/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/output.csv\' (Errcode: 30 "Read-only file system")')
```

What is the problem in this code? Why  I can't export it to .csv?

Comment: Can't you try to save where you have write permissions ? like /tmp/

Comment: Thank you @Marco, it is working!! :)

Comment: You can also flag a "plus" to comments when you find them useful :-)

Comment: @marco (&harley) maybe this could be turned into an *Answer* that gets accepted (so the question doesn't show up as unanswered)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion umläute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to try saving your in a directory where you surely have write permissions like /tmp/

Like this:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='***',
    passwd='***',
    db='database1',
    use_unicode=True,
    charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select * 
from example_table1
into outfile '/tmp/myfile.csv'
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '';
```